# How do I debug a constructor function in an LD_PRELOAD library?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, ld-preload, gcc-attribute

When I'm writing a library meant to be used with `LD_PRELOAD`, how can I debug its `__attribute__((__constructor__))` functions? They always seem to run before GDB can stop the process. As an MCVE, run the following:

```bash
cat > preflight.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

__attribute__((__constructor__))
void preflight(void) {
    puts("Exiting from preflight");
    exit(42);
}
EOF
gcc -g -fPIC -shared preflight.c -o preflight.so
gdb /bin/true -ex 'set environment LD_PRELOAD ./preflight.so' \
              -ex 'set breakpoint pending on' \
              -ex 'break preflight' \
              -ex 'starti'
```

The end of the GDB output will look like this:

```
Function "preflight" not defined.
Breakpoint 1 (preflight) pending.
Starting program: /usr/bin/true 
Exiting from preflight
During startup program exited with code 42.
(gdb)
```

Observe that the `preflight` function ran before GDB stopped the program, even though I tried to set a breakpoint on it, and I used `starti`, which is supposed to break on the first instruction. What do I have to do differently to get GDB to break at the `preflight` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because by default, GDB uses a shell to start the program being debugged, and environment variables provided to `set environment` apply to the shell too, so my `preflight` function ran there. GDB doesn't debug the shell, so when it ran there, it didn't stop it. There are two choices for how to work around this:

1. Do `set startup-with-shell off`.
2. Instead of `set environment LD_PRELOAD ./preflight.so`, do `set exec-wrapper env LD_PRELOAD=./preflight.so`.

References: GDB's documentation, sections [4.2 Starting your Program](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Starting.html) and [4.4 Your Program's Environment](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Environment.html).